# Having a TextSwitcher and an ImageSwitcher in the same class has Issues. XAMARIN

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I tried so hard to find a solution, but couldn't find a thing.
This is what i wish to achieve,
[Can you have a textSwitcher and imageSwitcher in the same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529505/can-you-have-a-textswitcher-and-imageswitcher-in-the-same-class)

But I am unable to convert it into C# code. I am clueless as to the errors it gives as well.

I understand I need to create an inner class. But am confused as to how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the link you provided your inner class would look like this in Xamarin

```
public class TextSwitcherFactory : Java.Lang.Object, ViewSwitcher.IViewFactory
{
    public View MakeView()
    {
        TextView t = new TextView(Latest.this);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        t.setTextSize(36);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried a different method which worked well for me. This one worked too. Thanks again!